# bison parse error in runtime confusion

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, lex, logical-operators

I'm working on vmWare linux ubuntu on a bison-dlex project, and I have an error in my bison file which I can't get over. In my "line' definition I have " logExp '\n' " definition, but for some reason it never gets there even though it does recognize the expression as logExp.

```
line:
expr '\n'          { printf("\nExpression = %d\n", $1); }  
| logExp '\n'      { printf("\nNEVER GETS HERE!!\n"); }   //ERROR
;
logExp:
expr AND expr    { $$ = 0 ; printf("\n$1=%d, $3=%d\n",$1,$3); } //PRINTS GOOD
| AND            {  } 
;
```

input:

```
 5&&6
```

output:

```
  $1=5, $3=6
  Error: parse error
```

If it recognizes the logExp, how come it doesn't recognize the line above??
..HELP ?

Comment: You do pass along the newline from the lexer to the parser?

Comment: yes, I do have ".|[\n]     return yytext[0];" in my lex file.
I also notice it catches the int twice as i expect

Comment: But did you verify that your scanner is working as expected? Hint: enable tracing in your scanner, your parser or both (see manuals; it's very easy). Automatic tracing will tell you a lot more about what is going on than inserting printf calls, and it is much less work.